# Did I find a bug in useState? Or am I not understanding how it works?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, graphql, use-state

I have this state updater that takes data object from a graphQL query, and reorganizes it into a single array in state, removing any data that comes back undefined || 0 length array.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (data !== undefined) {
      var e: Group[]
      var arrays = Object.values(data) as Group[][]
      for (e of arrays) {
        if (checkEmptyArray(e)) {
          console.log(e)
          // don't remove this const, code doesn't work without it.
          const destructured = [...e]
          setDataArray(prevState => [...prevState, ...destructured])
        }
      }
    }
  }, [data])
```

Works totally fine as it is. As soon as you replace `...destructured` with `...e`, it fails to work.

This seems very odd to me. Is it a bug? or do I not understand something?

Comment: Probably not a bug but can you put that in a sandbox?

Answer (score 1):

So ... what I guess is happening is something like; when you use e it gets modified by the "for (e of arrays)" loop before the "prevState => [...prevState, ...e]" gets properly evaluated, whereas "const destructured = [...e]" creates a new object to be passed to the function each time.

On a side note; are you sure you want to be calling setDataArray() inside of a loop, my guess is that would call multiple re-renders.